# Google Map iOS - Zoom animation does not work the same way on two different phones (iPhone X vs iPhone 7)

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, zooming

Here is my method :

```
private func animateCamera(lat: Double, long: Double, zoom: Float) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
         CATransaction.begin()
         CATransaction.setValue(1, forKey: kCATransactionAnimationDuration)
         let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat, longitude: long, zoom: zoom)
         self.mapView.animate(to: camera)
         CATransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

Here is how I call it :

```
animateCamera(lat: obs.position.latitude, long: obs.position.longitude, zoom: 7)
```

The zoom animation is working on an iPhone X.

On the other hand, on an iPhone 7, the zoom animation isn't centered on my destination point when it's finished (the lat/lon passed as parameters).

Is it because of different screen resolution ?

How should I handle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the long-form initializer on the camera position method and a more modern approach to setting the duration of your `CATransaction`:

```
private func animateCamera(lat: Double, long: Double, zoom: Float) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(1)
        CATransaction.setAnimationTimingFunction(CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.25, 0.75, 0.25, 1)) // you can add a timing curve too btw
        self.mapView.animate(to: GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat, longitude: long, zoom: zoom, bearing: self.mapView.camera.bearing, viewingAngle: self.mapView.camera.viewingAngle))
        CATransaction.commit()

    }

}
```

This produces the same result in all of my simulators.

Comment: Still the same. I was hoping you were right... I don't know what can create this behavior.

Comment: Post your entire view controller